# how to generate TECH_DISCOVERED intent on button click

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard

I want to send apdu to a nfc card when I click on button.
If I write onnewIntent() in my code when I come nfc card near phone I have a new intent. but I want to generate a TECH_DISCOVERED intent when I click a button an
CertificateGeneration()

this is my code:

```
public class CertificateGenerationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText txtName;
EditText txtfamily;
EditText txtNCode;
EditText txtSimPass;

private List<Integer> mChannelIds;
//SubjectPublicKeyInfo publickeyobj;
byte[] strCmd=null;

byte[] Resp;
byte[] cert;
Intent intentobj;


private OnClickListener btnOnclickListener=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


            CertificateGeneration();


    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_certificate_generation);
    Button btnSendReq=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnSendReq.setOnClickListener(btnOnclickListener);
    txtName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    txtfamily=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_family);
    txtNCode=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_ncode);
    txtSimPass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_simpass);


}

private void CertificateGeneration()
{

    byte[] csrdata=null,pkcs10req=null;



    Intent IntObj=new Intent(CertificateGenerationActivity.this,appletcommunication.class);
    IntObj.setAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    IntObj.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG,getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));


    appletcommunication appletclass=new appletcommunication(intentobj);
    if(!appletclass.ReadyConnection)
        return;//nfc communication not erady
    //cal method login in applet
    byte[] pin=new byte[] {(byte)1,(byte)2,(byte)3,(byte)4};
    appletclass.Login(pin);
}
```

}

but these code are mistake

```
     Intent IntObj=new Intent(CertificateGenerationActivity.this,appletcommunication.class);
    IntObj.setAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    IntObj.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG,getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));
```

becausetag is null when I get tag in this line,

```
  Parcelable tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

Comment: I searched a lot for a week but I don't know why I get negative point for this question

Comment: It's not good approach, NFC is not design in this way for Android. You could have a button in your app which start to catch nfc tag, and ask user to tap it, when it tap then proceed

Comment: Thank you very much